# Why isn't A a variable?

Tags: java

aa[i1] takes the user input and breaks it into single chars. For example: dog becomes d, o, g. I have an if statement which if aa[i1] is equal to "A", "B", "C"... it'll tell the user so. The error is when aa[i1] == A, A isn't a variable?

[image]

Comment: You need to put quotes around A if you want to check if it is actually the letter A. Or define a variable, A, that equals 'A'.

Comment: @Steve it worked thanks a lot! Still learning the syntax

Comment: I think you meant to have that last `if` statement inside the `for` loop? As it stands, `i1` will be equal to `t`, the length of the string (poor variable name, BTW), so `aa[i1]` will throw an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, **please *never*** post code as an image. Second, I've replaced your prompt and input with a constant for the sake of demonstration. Third, you need to surround your constant characters with single quotes (to make them constant characters, **or** you could define a character constant `final char A = 'A';`). Fourth, `String` has a method for copying its' internals to a `char[]`. Finally, I would prefer `printf` to string concatenation. Like,

```
String a = "ANGRY AARDVARK";
char[] aa = a.toCharArray();
for (int i = 0; i < aa.length; i++) {
    System.out.printf("Character at index %d=%c%n", i, aa[i]);
    if (aa[i] == 'A') {
        System.out.println("Character is A");
    }
}
```